# how properly delete cookies?

Tags: cookies, selenium, webdriver

I use `Selenium Webdriver`, I want clear cookies before execute test. I use code from official 'Selenium` site. This is code:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie loadedCookie : allCookies) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s", loadedCookie.getName(), loadedCookie.getValue()));
}
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

But I get notification: `- Cookie cannot be resolved to a type, Set cannot be resolved to a type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is of `java.util` package.

The [`Cookie`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html) is of `org.openqa.selenium` package.

You need to import those two classes to make your code work:

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
```

To make the suffering less painful, every modern Java IDE has an automatic function for this:

- In Eclipse, it's called "Organize imports" and sits under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
- In IntelliJ, it's called "Optimize imports" and sits under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.
- In NetBeans, it's also called somehow and sits under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your imports.  I suspect that you are using the javax cookie when you need the selenium one.

```
javax.servlet.http.Cookie

org.openqa.selenium.Cookie
```

Comment: that's it, first notification disappeared than I added org.openqa.selenium.Cookie to import, but second (Set cannot be resolved to a type) is still. Than I add javax.servlet.http.Cookie  - once again two notifications appears